# Parsing string date to date format

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having issues parsing a string to a date format.

This is my string
`7/13/2022 9:46 AM`

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time), I'm trying `PARSE_DATETIME("%x %R %p", datetime_closed)`
or `PARSE_DATETIME("%D %E4Y %R %p", "7/13/2022 9:46 AM")`

I've tried other combinations but none of them works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format below:

```
PARSE_DATETIME('%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p', "7/13/2022 9:46 AM")
```

The output:

[image: parse_datetime_output]

Answer (score 1):

Use `PARSE_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p", datetime_closed)` to get datetime or `DATE(PARSE_DATETIME("%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p", datetime_closed))` to get date